# Sabre 405: Method Not Allowed

Tags: authentication, sabre

I am trying to authenticate Sabre Api and not sure why I get the error "405: Method not allowed."  Here is the code.  The credentials are correct.  I have them blanked out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
        'url': 'https://api.sabre.com/v1/auth/token',
        'data': 'grant_type=client_credentials',
        'dataType': 'jsonp',
        'type': 'post',
        'headers': {'Authorization': 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
       }
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems that POST isn't an allowed method then.

Comment: I believe it is.  I tried get as well.  Same thing.

Comment: Nothing I'm reading suggests that the API is made to be used with javascript.  Eg, you'd need to use an actual client to access the data, like cURL.

Comment: On top of the fact that anyone could just steal your auth information, given js is visible to the client computer.

Comment: Was just actually using this to test to see if it was working from my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still an issue, was just looking for some things and bumped into this.

If I try to with `'dataType': 'json'`, instead of `jsonp` I get a successful response using my credentials.

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

The Sabre API service for authenticating as you mention accepts POST method in authentication requests. See below reference:

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_basics/authentication

If looking for pure Javascript implementation, Modern browsers support HTTP very well via the XMLHttpRequest API, which, despite its name, is not limited to XML representations.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

Would recommend looking into this approach if looking into consuming REST for JavaScript.

More documented information on this API is found here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/